# Getting 404 error sometimes while reading a file,how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting 404 error for reading while reading some files only,remaining files shows data without error.i not able to find where i did wrong,here i am saving uploaded file like below.Any help greatly appreciated.

```
 File ftemp= new File(basePath +"//InvoiceInventory//"+store.name+"//SHOP//"+invoiceType+"//");
```

And my ui page code is:

```
 @for(invoice <- invoiceList) {
  <tr>
    @if(invoice.storeId != 1){
    <td><a href="/INVOICEPROCESSINGSYSTEM/@invoice.filePath" class="fancyboxPDF" title="@invoice.fileName" onclick="OpenFancyBox('@invoice.id');">@invoice.fileName</a></td>
     }
   @if(invoice.storeId == 1){
   <td><a href="/INVOICEPROCESSINGSYSTEM/@invoice.filePath" class="fancyboxPDF" title="@invoice.fileName" onclick="OpenFancyBoxForHeadOffice('@invoice.id');">@invoice.fileName</a></td>
    }

    <td>@invoice.uploadedDate</td>
    <td>@invoice.invoiceType</td>
    <td>@Store.find.byId(invoice.storeId)</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

my jquery method is:

```
    function OpenFancyBox(invoiceId){
    //alert(invoiceId);

    $(".fancyboxPDF").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        width:1200,
        height:1000,
        autoSize: true,
        type: 'iframe',
        loop : false,
        helpers : { 
          overlay : {closeClick: false}, // disables close when outside clcik 
          title : {  // put title on the top
            type: 'inside',
            position : 'top'
            }
        },
        beforeShow: function () {
            if (this.title) {
                // New line
                this.title += '<br />';

                // Add Form to Title
                this.title += '<form action="/InvoiceInventory/list/move/'+invoiceId+'" method="post"><div class="table-responsive"><table style="background-color: white;border-color: #fff;" class="table table-bordered"><tr><td><div class="clearfix" id="category_field"><label for="category">Invoice Category</label><div class="input"><select id="invoiceCategoryAtFancyBox" name="category" onchange="disableSupplierListAtFancyBox()" required><option class="blank" value="">-- Choose --</option><option value="Fuel">Fuel</option><option value="Others">Others</option></select> <span class="help-inline"></span></div></div></td><td><div class="clearfix" id="invoiceDate_field"><label for="invoiceDate">Invoice Date</label><div class="input"><input type="text" class="datepickerFancyBox" name="invoiceDate" required><span class="help-inline"></span></div></div></td><td><div class="clearfix" id="paymentTerms_field"><label for="paymentTerms">Payment Terms</label><div class="input"><select id="paymentTermsFancyBox" name="paymentTerms" required><option class="blank" value="">-- Choose --</option><option value="CashPaid">CashPaid</option><option value="DD">DD</option><option value="FortNightly">FortNightly</option><option value="Weekly">Weekly</option><option value="Monthly">Monthly</option><option value="Others">Others</option></select> <span class="help-inline"></span></div></div></td><td><div class="clearfix" id="supplier_field"><label for="supplier">Supplier</label><div class="input"><select id="supplierListAtFancyBox" name="supplier" required onfocus="selectBoxOptionsInFancyBox()"><option class="blank" value="">-- Choose a Supplier--</option></select> <span class="help-inline"></span></div></div></td><td><input type="submit" value="Done" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/InvoiceInventory/delete/'+invoiceId+'" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('+" 'Are You sure want to Delete ?' "+')">Delete</a></td></tr></table></div></form>';

               }
        },
        iframe: {
            preload: false // fixes issue with iframe and IE
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Do you want to debug your jquery code ?

Comment: no i want to clear 404 error while reading a file